# Grub2 bootloader not working after fresh install of Ubuntu 9.10

Tags: ubuntu, grub

After a fresh install (reformatting the entire disk) of Ubuntu 9.10 or Mythbuntu 9.10, system freezes while loading Grub (grub2).  Normal rescue techniques (booting from live CD and running update-grub) don't work.  Update-grub fails with:

```
Generating grub.cfg ...
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.bin
grep: /proc/mounts: No such file or directory
Cannot find list of partitions!
done
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer seems to be disconnect any RAID array(s) on your motherboard.

I had a 4 disk RAID5 array in addition to the disk I was installing onto.  When I disconnected those 4 disks so the installer only saw one hard disk, the install went perfectly.